# Проблема с CSS таблицами

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Есть сайт http://apartment-inn.kz/. Если посмотреть то между то между первым слайдом и вторым есть пространство пару пикселей. На фото выделил красным. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Консоль разработчика пробовали открывать? Изменять стили элементов, удалять элементы пробовали?

Comment: да пробовал, но там и стилей не так много, но вот эти 2 пикселя внизу непонятно что там делают((((

Comment: задайте для изображения display:block

Comment: @soledar10 Спасибо! Ответ верный!